# Is {$u_{1},u_{2},\cdots,u_{k},v$} linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

### **Question:**

Given {$u_{1},u_{2},\cdots,u_{k},u_{k+1}$} is a set of linear independent vectors in $R^n$

and $v = u_{1}+u_{2}+\cdots+u_{k}+u_{k+1}$,

prove that {$u_{1},u_{2},\cdots,u_{k},v$} linearly independent.

### **My solution:**

My definition of {$u_{1},u_{2},\cdots,u_{k},v$} is 
$$ \lambda_1u_1+\dots+\lambda_ku_k+\lambda_{k+1}v=0 $$, where  $\lambda_i$ (with $i\in\{1,\dots,k+1\}$.

Suppose that $\lambda_{k+1}=0$, this would mean that $\{u_1,\dots,u_k\}$ must be linearly dependent, which is contradictory.

I probably messed up my concepts. Please advice, thanks.

Comment: @MeeSeongIm Nope.

Comment: You have to prove that all $\lambda$'s are zero. For this, put the definition of $v$ into your equation.

Comment: @idolo I read the problem too fast. I see. Yes, $\{u_{1},u_{2},\cdots,u_{k},v\}$ forms a set of linearly independent vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the given statement, we know that the only scalars, $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $$\alpha_1 u_1 + \alpha_2 u_2 + \cdots + \alpha_{k+1} u_{k+1} = 0 \tag{*}$$ are $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = \cdots = \alpha_{k+1}=0 $.

Now consider $$\beta_1 u_1 + \beta_2 u_2 + \cdots + \beta_k u_k + \beta_{k+1} v = 0$$ $$\Rightarrow \beta_1 u_1 + \beta_2 u_2 + \cdots + \beta_k u_k + \beta_{k+1} (u_1 + u_2 + \cdots + u_{k+1}) = 0$$ $$\Rightarrow (\beta_1 + \beta_{k+1})u_1 + \cdots + (\beta_k + \beta_{k+1})u_k + \beta_{k+1} u_{k+1} = 0$$ Notice this equation is the same as $(*)$, with $\alpha_1 = \beta_1 + \beta_{k+1}$,$\cdots$,  $\alpha_k = \beta_k + \beta_{k+1}$, $\alpha_{k+1} = \beta_{k+1}$.

We know that all the $\alpha_i=0$, so $\beta_1 + \beta_{k+1} = 0, \beta_2 + \beta_{k+1}=0, \cdots, \beta_k + \beta_{k+1}=0, \beta_{k+1}=0$ and $\{u_1, u_2, \cdots, u_k, v\}$ is thus linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$ \lambda_1u_1+\dots+\lambda_ku_k+\lambda_{k+1}v=0 $$
$$\implies \lambda_1u_1+\dots+\lambda_ku_k+\lambda_{k+1}\left(u_{1}+u_{2}+\cdots+u_{k}+u_{k+1}\right)=0$$
$$\implies (\lambda_1+\lambda_{k+1})u_1+\dots+(\lambda_k+\lambda_{k+1})u_k+\lambda_{k+1}u_{k+1}=0$$

What can you conclude from the last equation?

Comment: $(\lambda_1+\lambda_{k+1}) =0, (\lambda_2+\lambda_{k+1}) =0, \cdots, (\lambda_k+\lambda_{k+1}) =0$, which implies that they are linearly independent? Why is it safe to assume that $\lambda_{k+1}$ is also = $0$, when it's not in the form $(\lambda_{k+1}+\lambda_{k+1})$? Thanks again.

Comment: Note that you can rename the coefficients to $\alpha_1$ to $\alpha_{k+1}$. As we know that the vectors $u_1,\ldots, u_{k+1}$ are independent it directly implies that the vectors $u_1,\ldots, v$ are independent. If that was not the case then we would have shown that $u_1,\ldots, u_{k+1}$ are dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a linear combination of the second set's vectors is always a linear combination of the first set's vectors (via the distributive property).

Linear independence is a condition on linear combinations of a set. So if the condition holds for linear combinations of the first set - and it does, by hypothesis - it also holds for linear combinations of the second set.